# Implementing IDisposable for an Excel class

Tags: c#, excel, memory-management, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a class (in a C# MVC 5 project) that originally had a `using` block within a single method, and it got to be very huge after placing formatting statements and other code in the `using` block.

I am using the Nuget Epplus package to export a model's contents to an Excel document, and all of the tutorials I can find place the `ExcelPackage` variable within a `using` block.

```
using (ExcelProject excelProject = new ExcelProject())
{
   // lots of code happens nere, making it bloated and ugly
}
```

In order to reorganize the class and make the `ExportToExcel` method truly that -- something that only outputs a byte[] array and doesn't contain statements that can be moved into other methods -- I took the `excelProject` variable out of the `using` block and made it a class-level variable. That's when Visual Studio code analysis told me I needed to implement `IDisposable`.

> warning CA1001: Microsoft.Design : Implement IDisposable on 'EpplusExcelPackage' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'ExcelPackage'.

I have encountered programmers who tell me things like, "Warnings are meant to be ignored! Turn them off!" I disagree with that and am making the time to address this warning.

I combed through the available `IDisposable` tutorials and found inspiration for the three methods at the very bottom of the class: `public void Dispose()`, `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)`, and `~EpplusExcelPackage()`.

Am I correctly implementing IDisposable in this class?

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

// uses Nuget Epplus package

namespace WebApplication1.CentralFunctions
{
    public class EpplusExcelPackage<T> : IDisposable
    {
        private IEnumerable<T> data;
        private byte[] response;
        private string worksheetTitle;
        private ExcelPackage excelPackage = null;
        private ExcelWorksheet worksheet;

        public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data)
        {
            this.data = Data;
            this.worksheetTitle = null;
            excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
            CreateAndLoadWorksheet();
        }

        public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data, string WorksheetTitle)
        {
            this.data = Data;
            this.worksheetTitle = WorksheetTitle;
            excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
            CreateAndLoadWorksheet();
        }

        public void CreateAndLoadWorksheet()
        {
            excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            worksheet.Name = "Sheet1";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, true);
        }

        public void IdentifyDataTypes()
        {
            // Gather type info of T properties.
            PropertyInfo[] dataPropertiesInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            int i = 1;
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo dataPropertyInfo in dataPropertiesInfos)
            {
                if (dataPropertyInfo.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("[System.DateTime]"))
                {
                    worksheet.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        public byte[] ExportToExcel()
        {
            response = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

            return response;
        }

        /* Inspired by http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/413887/Understanding-and-Implementing-IDisposable-Interfa */


        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing == true)
            {
                if (excelPackage != null)
                    excelPackage.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                // The example said nothing goes here.
            }
        }

        ~EpplusExcelPackage()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use the disposable pattern at all? You don't hold and unmanaged resources, so you can simply forward the dispose call to the holder. No point in implementing a finalizer at all.

Comment: Because code analysis gave a warning: "warning CA1001: Microsoft.Design : Implement IDisposable on 'EpplusExcelPackage<T>' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'ExcelPackage'." That's why.

Comment: Implementing `IDisposable` makes sense, the finalizer does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost.

From the [MSDN docs on the Disposable Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **✓ DO** allow the `Dispose(bool)` method to be called more than once. The
>   method might choose to do nothing after the first call.

This is typically done by introducing a private boolean member variable and a guard clause.

```
    private bool disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed) 
            return;

        if (disposing == true)
        {
            if (excelPackage != null)
                excelPackage.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            // The example said nothing goes here.
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
```

And now you have it. Of course, no harm would have been done without the guard clause in your particular case, but I find it good to just implement the same boiler plate every time. It kind of burns into your brain after a while.

This allows us to follow another bullet point from the doc.

> **✓ DO** throw an `ObjectDisposedException` from any member that cannot be
>   used after the object has been disposed of.

So, in any public member of your class that uses `excelPackage`, you should check the new `disposed` field and throw accordingly. For example:

```
    public byte[] ExportToExcel()
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException();
        }

        response = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

        return response;
    }
```

---

Some other notes:

- `if (disposing == true)` is exactly equivalent to `if( disposing )`.
- Why, *why*, ***why*** is `private byte[] response;` available to your whole class?!

  It's only used in one method, so declare it there and reduce its scope.
- Do you want null reference exceptions? Because this is how you get null reference exceptions. (Sorry, [Archer reference...](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-you-want-ants))

  > ```
  >         foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo dataPropertyInfo in dataPropertiesInfos)
  >     {
  >         if (dataPropertyInfo.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("[System.DateTime]"))
  > ```

  We have no idea if `dataPropertyInfo.PropertyType` has a reference when you call `ToString()` on it. *Okay*, so given the context, it's probably fine. I do expect it to have a reference, but this pattern will bite you eventually if you blindly call `ToString()` on things without null checking them first.

  Also, I'm not very good at reflection in .Net, but I suspect there's a better way to check the property type than by casting it to a string and then running `Contains(...)` on it. I'd say some research is due on how to do this more cleanly.
- Your constructors have a lot of duplication.

  > ```
  >      public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data)
  >     {
  >         this.data = Data;
  >         this.worksheetTitle = null;
  >         excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
  >         CreateAndLoadWorksheet();
  >     }
  >
  >      public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data, string WorksheetTitle)
  >     {
  >         this.data = Data;
  >         this.worksheetTitle = WorksheetTitle;
  >         excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
  >         CreateAndLoadWorksheet();
  >     }
  > ```

  You can clean this up by chaining them together.

  ```
      public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data)
          :this(Data, null)
      {
      }

      public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data, string WorksheetTitle)
      {
          this.data = Data;
          this.worksheetTitle = WorksheetTitle;
          excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
          CreateAndLoadWorksheet();
      }
  ```

  Which in turn, highlights that you're setting the worksheet title to `null` instead of giving it a reasonable default value.

---

In summary, this is a lot of work and complexity to add to your project. As you can see, it's a bit difficult to get the Disposable pattern right. Weigh your options here. This is really only worth it if you're calling this code a lot.

Every time I've ever found myself thinking that I need to implement `IDisposable`, I was wrong. Each and every time I was able to create a cohesive class that avoided keeping disposable objects as members. Instead, I found ways to kept each call to the disposable object short lived. I challenge you to see if you really need the `excelPackage` to live for the lifetime of this class. I would try to keep it inside of a `using` block in the method you'd like to call.

Comment: This is very useful. A really good question comes from "calling this code a lot." I envision multiple controllers calling this class, perhaps as much as 40 times an hour on peak days in this intranet MVC website.  Does that qualify as a lot?

Comment: Aye. I'd say it does, and you were right to extract a class. The question is "does this class really need to implement IDisposable?" I'm not quite familiar enough with what it does, but I would really strive to make it so that it doesn't need to.

Comment: That's a good question I'll be asking myself over the next few days. "Can I make the class functional, organized, maintainable, and adaptable by keeping the relevant code inside the `using` statement?"  It can be done, especially if it is possible to get IDisposable wrong.

Comment: Well, come back and post a new question when you're done. I'd like to see what you come up with.

Comment: `this pattern will bite you eventually if you blindly call ToString() on things without null checking them first` Or [null propagating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx) them if you want to ignore nulls: `dataPropertyInfo?.PropertyType?.ToString()?.Contains("[System.DateTime]") == true`

Comment: @RubberDuck -- In the end, you're right. Stick with the `using` block. I posted a separate answer showing my revised code along with other spot improvements. I think I'm better off then when I started.

Answer (score 3):

`ExcelPackage` is a *managed* resource so you don't need any of that `Dispose(bool disposing)` or `CG.SupressFinalize(this)` hogwash. Simply call `excelPackage.Dispose()` once you are done using it and call it a day (after all that's what the `using` statement does too).

Only implement the `IDisposable` interface if you really need to move the disposing responsibility to the user of the class (you probably don't) and if you do your `Dispose()` method should simply be

```
public void Dispose()
{
    excelPackage.Dispose()
}
```

(You don't even need to check the reference for `null` first since you initialize it from the constructor so it should never be null and if it is you have a bug that needs to be fixed rather than swallowed.)

All that disposing boilerplate code is only needed if your class holds a reference to an *unmanaged* resource and in that case managing(!) that unmanaged resource should be the *sole responsibility* of the class.

Never should your class reference multiple unmanaged resources and never ever should it reference both managed and unmanaged resources.

Comment: I was skeptical of this answer at first, but [this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2013/01/20/the-dispose-pattern-as-an-anti-pattern/) has convinced me that you're correct. ++

Comment: Another very good article explaining why we only need to implement a single `Dispose()` method. http://sietch.net/ViewNewsItem.aspx?NewsItemID=246

Comment: @RubberDuck As someone who often works with unmanaged code, your skepticism surprised me.

Comment: @Pharap my skepticism is likely a result of following the guidelines blindly, without understanding *why* the guidelines are what they are. I fell victim to Cargo Cult programming. Shame on me.

Comment: @RubberDuck Unfortunately 'helpful articles' can sometimes end up being propegators of bad practice because they're written by people who either don't understand the complexities involved or cut the important stuff in an attempt to dumb things down for more casual programmers. For an in depth look into all the common misbeliefs people have about the garbage collector I recommend Eric Lippert's ["When Everything You Know Is Wrong"](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) (aka 'The Garbage Collector: A Horror Story About Nasal Demons').

Comment: I tried as you suggested @Roman and I got the code analysis warning: "warning CA1001: Microsoft.Design : Implement IDisposable on 'EpplusExcelPackage<T>' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'ExcelPackage'." Re-implemening IDispoable, I got two further warnings telling me to iplement IDisposable correctly.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge See spenders comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11793119

Comment: Also note those are warnings. They indicate there _might_ be a problem. Not that there is.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank everyone for their helpful comments and suggestions. I placed my `ExcelPackage` code back within the `using` block -- IDispose seems too complicated to me at this time, so I'm going to opt for the simpler option.

As for one of my earlier concerns about the `using` block blowing up with lots of code -- I haven't yet developed future code that the customers haven't yet determined -- I think I worked out a better approach for organizing and allowing for future growth: extracting blocks of code into their own void functions and calling them from within the `using` block.

The only public code other than the constructor is a public byte[] method. This is the Excel document that is sent back to the MVC website controller for the user to save where they choose.

I also chanced into a better means of type-checking for datetime properties when using Reflection: `if (dataPropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))`.

Here is the approach that I am going with for now.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;

// uses Nuget Epplus package

// User uses class constructor and the class does the rest
// 1: Add report information to document
// 2: Identify datetime columns and format column in Excel document as shortdate
// 3: TODO: Apply chosen theme (where 0 = plain format)
// 4: Export byte[] to the controller to be saved as a file

namespace WebApplication1.CentralFunctions
{
    public class EpplusExcelPackage<T>
    {
        private IEnumerable<T> data;
        private string reportName;
        private int chosenTheme;

        public EpplusExcelPackage(IEnumerable<T> Data, string ReportName, int ChosenTheme)
        {
            this.data = Data;
            this.reportName = ReportName;
            this.chosenTheme = ChosenTheme;

            // All ExcelPackage code is placed inside a "using block".
            // Formatting, reflection type-checking, and other future code
            // are placed in separate functions that are called from the using block
        }

        private void IdentifyDataTypes(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
        {
            // Gather type info of T properties.
            PropertyInfo[] dataPropertiesInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            // from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180730/c-sharp-determine-a-nullable-property-datetime-type-when-using-reflection

            int i = 1;
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo dataPropertyInfo in dataPropertiesInfos)
            {
                if (dataPropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))  // field is nullable in model; 
                {
                    worksheet.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        // byte[] sent to controller for user to save as a file
        public byte[] ExportToExcel()
        {
            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                // create worksheet
                excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                worksheet.Name = "Sheet1";

                // add header information
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Report Name";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = reportName;
                worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "Timestamp";
                worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                // load data from collection
                worksheet.Cells[5, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, true);

                // Identify datetime columns in model and format accordingly
                IdentifyDataTypes(worksheet);

                // TODO: apply chosen theme               

                return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally think this is a big improvement. Much simpler. One last note. You can return from inside the `using` block. The. You don't need the `response` variable at all. Happy coding!

Comment: Good idea. I just applied that. Even better.